# C# MVC Run controller code weekly

Tags: c#

I have a controller that runs and gets data from a database and sends an email through to the client.

This email setting gets set in a form that is saved to a table with the email recipients. I need to run this on a schedule, which the user (client) defines in a form. Here the client can select either weekly, biweekly or monthly.

From here and after this is saved in the database, it is easy enough to pull from the database, but I need a way to run this every time at the time specified by the client (weekly, biweekly, or monthly). I was thinking of using a webjob (Azure) to do this but I am not sure how to approach this.

So

1. Are there any issues with this approach?
2. What are some of the other options?
3. Any recommendations?

Comment: Have a look at HangFire (http://hangfire.io/). This is exactly the kind of task it is built for

Comment: Unfortunately this type of question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as you're asking for recommendations and opinions, and it's very broad. Also, there's no *best* way to do it (again, just opinions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at solutions that are designed for this? Why re-invent the wheel?

Take a look at [Hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io/)

You can then just do the following:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(BatchClient.Start());
```

Or you can add a Recurring job:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => BatchClient.Start(), Cron.Daily);
```

There are also other options also worth investigating e.g. [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Comment: Nice component, but how can anyone make version 1.5 and still have fundamental problems, seriously?
http://hangfire.io/blog/2016/06/17/hangfire-1.5.8.html#.V2P56asZluo.twitter

Comment: @Dusan I was just giving some options :) There is always Quartz that I also suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don know if this is the best approach out there, but we use this in our company projects (exactly for sending scheduled emails):

1. We use Cron Expression to define frequency of an action that needs to be perfomed;
2. We use Quartz.NET to get the next date when this action should be performed;
3. For the checking the dates and running actions we are using a WCF service, running in a Windows Service on its own thread.

It might be to complex for your need, but it is pretty flexible. You have to decide where and how you store cron expressions and next dates. For the Cron Expression we use the DB next dates we keep in memory.